# Почему компонент в битрикс 1с catalog.element только при входе с правами admina?

Tags: битрикс

Почему компонент в битрикс 1с catalog.element только при входе с правами admina? Не пойму почему так. В админке-детальный просмотр работает, а для всех остальных не работает.  Доступы в инфоблоке проверил. Буду рад любой помощи.

Компонент catalog:
//element.php
https://disk.yandex.ru/d/gTsl-foQUnNv2Q

Шаблон компонента:
catalog.element
https://disk.yandex.ru/d/gTsl-foQUnNv2Q

А это страница  с детальной страницей товара: http://akkuver-bitrix-njqo1.tw1.ru/catalog/ventura-gp/ventura-gp-6-4-5/

Comment: Там что-то странное. Если перейти в список товаров http://akkuver-bitrix-njqo1.tw1.ru/catalog/ventura-gp/ и оттуда открыть товар http://akkuver-bitrix-njqo1.tw1.ru/catalog/ventura-gp/ventura-gp-12-12/ то он открвается. Если на этой странице товара обновить страницу, то он больше не показывается.

Comment: Да, я тоже заметил эту странность. Мне это сайт достался по наследству от другого разработчика. Теперь целый день понять не могу почему так происходит) Может подскажете  в каком направление копать?

Comment: Возможно когда первый раз открываем товар, компонент или что-то еще сохраняет какой-то cookie и в следующий раз это мешает.

Comment: Отключил автокеширование-теперь работает. Буду разбираться в этом направление

Comment: И можно еще в направлении Композитного режима "копать". В element.php, template.php, строка $this->setFrameMode(true); - голосует ЗА или $this->setFrameMode(false); - голосует ПРОТИВ. Побробнее тут https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=39&LESSON_ID=3255